# cannot upload a canvas.toDataURL image: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, xmlhttprequest

I cannot upload a canvas.toDataURL image: I get the warning:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/
```

and then the error:

```
no element found testSave.php:23:1
```

As in this [tutorial](http://permadi.com/2010/10/html5-saving-canvas-image-data-using-php-and-ajax/), my JavaScript is:

```
var canvasData = testCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST",'testSave.php',false);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
ajax.send(canvasData );
```

and testSave.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
  // Get the data
  $imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];

  // Remove the headers (data:,) part.
  // A real application should use them according to needs such as to     check image type
  $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);

  // Need to decode before saving since the data we received is already base64 encoded
  $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

//echo "unencodedData".$unencodedData;

// Save file. This example uses a hard coded filename for testing,
// but a real application can specify filename in POST variable
$fp = fopen( 'test.png', 'wb' );
fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
fclose( $fp );
}
?>
```

Comment: You are trying to do a synchronous XMLHttpRequest(which is deprecated) and testSave.php may be not found.

Comment: ok, it is deprecated, I know it, but what should I do instead to upload this image? The file testSave.php is found, when I click on the link, it gives me the file

Comment: If the PHP is not been executed, then you don't have a web server(or is not properly configured)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an ugly solution to my problem:

1. In HTML `<head>`, add:

`<script src="../static/js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>`

1. Replace the JavaScript part of the question with:

   ```
   var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "upload_ajax",
   data: { 
      imgBase64: dataURL
     }
   }).done(function(o) {
   console.log('saved'); 
   // If you want the file to be visible in the browser 
   // - please modify the callback in javascript. All you
   // need is to return the url to the file, you just saved 
   // and than put the image in your browser.
   });
   ```
2. Use Flask instead of PHP, with the relevant part of the code being:

`from flask import json as jsonflask
import cv2
import uuid
import os
import base64
import numpy as np
import StringIO
import urllib
from PIL import Image`

`def request_to_nparray(request):
    output=request.form['imgBase64']
    head = "data:image/png;base64,"
    assert(output.startswith(head))
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(output[len(head):])
    imgF = StringIO.StringIO()
    imgF.write(imgdata)
    imgF.seek(0)
    img = Image.open(imgF)
    buf = np.fliplr(np.asarray(img))
    buf = np.asarray(img)
    bufshape=buf.shape
    rgbFrame = np.zeros(bufshape, dtype=np.uint8)
    rgbFrame[:, :, 0] = buf[:, :, 2]
    rgbFrame[:, :, 1] = buf[:, :, 1]
    rgbFrame[:, :, 2] = buf[:, :, 0]
    ourframe = np.copy(rgbFrame)
    return ourframe`

```
`@app.route('/upload_ajax', methods = ['POST'])
def ajax_request():
    photo_array= request_to_nparray(request)
    f_name = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.jpg'
    _photo_path= os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f_name)
    cv2.imwrite(_photo_path, photo_array)
    return jsonflask.dumps({'filename':f_name})`
```